# Ruby instance variable across classes or a better way to share an object among classes within an instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instance-variables, multiple-instances

I'm working with an API gem, mavenlink_gem, that doesn't handle multiple users well. It uses an oauth token for authorization, but it seems that because this is defined at the class level rather than the instance level, multiple users accessing the app all end up using the same token (the token from the first use).

The `Client` class can be initialized as expected, and an oauth token can be provided for the instance (`Mavenlink::Client.new(oauth_token: "12345"`) and requests to the API are made through a `Mavenlink::Request` class which accepts a client object, or creates a new one if it isn't provided (this is part of the problem).

Example:

```
client = Mavenlink::Client.new(oauth_token: "12345") // OK
workspace = client.workspaces.find(1) // OK
participants = workspace.participants // Fails because calling the association intantiates a new Mavenlink::Request and does not pass it the `client`
```

When I call `save` on the resource (`workspace` in this example), it creates a new instance of `Mavenlink::Request` and doesn't pass in the `client` object as `workspace` is an instance of `Workspace < Model` and has no reference to the `client` instance.

Anyway, perhaps the code can do a better job of explaining it than I can....

client.rb:

```
module Mavenlink
  class Client
    ENDPOINT = 'https://api.mavenlink.com/api/v1/'.freeze

    # @param settings [ActiveSuppport::HashWithIndifferentAccess]
    def initialize(settings = Mavenlink.default_settings)
      @settings = settings
      # @oauth_token = settings[:oauth_token] or raise ArgumentError, 'OAuth token is not set'
      @oauth_token = Mavenlink.oauth_token or raise ArgumentError, 'OAuth token is not set'

      # TODO: implement with method_missing?
      # Declare API calls client.-->>workspaces<<---.create({})
      Mavenlink.specification.keys.each do |collection_name|
        singleton_class.instance_eval do
          define_method collection_name do
            ::Mavenlink::Request.new(collection_name, self)
          end
        end
      end
    end

...
```

request.rb:

```
module Mavenlink
  class Request
    include Enumerable

    attr_reader :client, :collection_name
    attr_accessor :scope

    # @param collection_name [String, Symbol]
    # @param client [Mavenlink::Client]
    def initialize(collection_name, client = Mavenlink::Client.new)
      @collection_name = collection_name
      @client = client
      @scope = ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new
    end

...
```

model.rb (the parent class for all resources, such as Workspace):
This is the method that ultimately makes the request

```
# @return [Mavenlink::Request]
def self.scoped
  Mavenlink::Request.new(collection_name) // At this point, I need to pass in client/@client/oauth_token or something...
end
```

So my rather long question revolves around whether I can have an instance variable (@client) across multiple classes. Or how best to get @client into the `Model` class since the request doesn't originate from `client`.

Here is the error trace:

```
1.9.3-p484 :001 > client = Mavenlink::Client.new(oauth_token: "12345")
 => #<Mavenlink::Client:0x007fab5bacc4a8 @settings={:oauth_token=>"12345"}, @oauth_token="12345"> 
1.9.3-p484 :002 > workspace = client.workspaces.first
I, [2015-03-26T13:18:41.170598 #89994]  INFO -- : [Maven] Started GET /workspaces with {}
 => {"title"=>"Jira Project II", "archived"=>false, "description"=>"", "due_date"=>"", "effective_due_date"=>"", "start_date"=>"", "budgeted"=>true, "change_orders_enabled"=>true, "updated_at"=>"2015-03-26T08:21:08-07:00", "created_at"=>"2015-02-18T09:55:53-08:00", "consultant_role_name"=>"Consultants", "client_role_name"=>"Clients", "percentage_complete"=>1, "access_level"=>"invitation", "exclude_archived_stories_percent_complete"=>false, "can_create_line_items"=>true, "default_rate"=>nil, "currency_symbol"=>"$", "currency_base_unit"=>100, "can_invite"=>true, "has_budget_access"=>true, "tasks_default_non_billable"=>false, "rate_card_id"=>nil, "workspace_invoice_preference_id"=>nil, "posts_require_privacy_decision"=>false, "require_time_approvals"=>false, "require_expense_approvals"=>false, "price"=>"TBD", "price_in_cents"=>nil, "budget_used"=>"$0", "over_budget"=>false, "currency"=>"USD", "expenses_in_burn_rate"=>true, "status"=>{"color"=>"green", "message"=>"Active"}, "permissions"=>{"can_upload_files"=>true, "can_private_message"=>true, "can_join"=>false, "is_participant"=>true, "access_level"=>"team_lead", "user_is_client"=>false}, "id"=>"7232855", "creator_id"=>"5207615"} 
1.9.3-p484 :003 > workspace.participants
ArgumentError: OAuth token is not set
    from /Users/Adam/Mavenlink/mavenlink_gem/lib/mavenlink/client.rb:8:in `initialize'
    from /Users/Adam/Mavenlink/mavenlink_gem/lib/mavenlink.rb:27:in `new'
    from /Users/Adam/Mavenlink/mavenlink_gem/lib/mavenlink.rb:27:in `client'
    from /Users/Adam/Mavenlink/mavenlink_gem/lib/mavenlink/request.rb:10:in `initialize'
    from /Users/Adam/Mavenlink/mavenlink_gem/lib/mavenlink/model.rb:36:in `new'
    from /Users/Adam/Mavenlink/mavenlink_gem/lib/mavenlink/model.rb:36:in `scoped'
    from /Users/Adam/Mavenlink/mavenlink_gem/lib/mavenlink/model.rb:221:in `request'
    from /Users/Adam/Mavenlink/mavenlink_gem/lib/mavenlink/model.rb:245:in `reload_association'
    from /Users/Adam/Mavenlink/mavenlink_gem/lib/mavenlink/model.rb:71:in `block in association'
    from (irb):3
    from /Users/Adam/Mavenlink/mavenlink_gem/bin/mavenlink-console:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/mavenlink-console:23:in `load'
    from /Users/Adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/mavenlink-console:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/Adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/Adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
1.9.3-p484 :004 >
```

It is worth noting that the `oauth_token` can be set at the module level in the `Mavenlink` module, which then fixes the issue for a singular user, however I found that when deployed as multi-tenant with multiple users logged in, each with different oauth_tokens, it did not use the correct one.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. I likely did not provide enough of an explanation for anyone to solve this, but let me know what other info I can post. Thanks!

Comment: I am trying to use the gem. it wasn't created by me, and I'm running into issues using it because my application is multi-user and the oauth_token is being set at the module/class level and seems to be applied across all instances.

Answer (score 0):

I think you found a real bug.  I'll make an issue on the GitHub Issues for the gem and we can take a look at fixing it.

https://github.com/mavenlink/mavenlink_gem/issues/17

Would you mind moving the discussion over there?